# a* giving inconsistent paths given at runtime

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I am implementing an a* algorithm for a randomly generated grid where B = a blocked tile and * = and open tile. Sometimes when I run the program, it comes up with the correct path, but sometimes it just infinitely loops through the same nodes. If it can't find a path, it is supposed to print out "path not found", but when it does, it is to print out the path. Currently the program is printing the path backwards, I need to make this change as well. I am attaching both my Node class, and my main driver.

Can somebody spot what is wrong, because I have not idea. Thanks!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class AStarCopy {
    public static int[][] grid;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        grid = new int[15][15];

        int startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol;
        Node startNode, goalNode;

        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);

        // assign values to the grid
        for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 15; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = 0;
                Double d = Math.random();
                if (d <= .10) {
                    grid[row][col] = 1; // for 10% squares set them as blocked
                }// close if
            }// close col
        }// close row

        // print out the grid
        System.out
        .print("_____________________________________________________________\n\n");
        for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 15; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == 1) {
                    System.out.print("| B ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("| * ");
                }// close else
            }// close col
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.println();
        }// close row
        System.out
        .print("_____________________________________________________________\n");

        System.out.println("Enter starting row: ");
        startRow = k.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter starting column: ");
        startCol = k.nextInt();

        // doesn't let user select blocked tile as start point
        while (grid[startRow][startCol] == 1) {
            System.out
            .println("You entered an invalid square please try again!");
            System.out.println("\nEnter starting row: ");
            startRow = k.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter starting col: ");
            startCol = k.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter end row: ");
        endRow = k.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter end column: ");
        endCol = k.nextInt();

        // doesn't let user select blocked tile as end point
        while (grid[endRow][endCol] == 1) {
            System.out
            .println("You entered an invalid square please try again!");
            System.out.println("\nEnter ending row: ");
            startRow = k.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter ending col: ");
            startCol = k.nextInt();
        }

        goalNode = new Node(endRow, endCol, grid[endRow][endCol]);
        startNode = new Node(startRow, startCol, grid[startRow][startCol]);
        startNode.setG(0);
        startNode.setH(getH(startNode, goalNode));
        startNode.setF();

        runAStarSearch(startNode, goalNode, grid);

    }

    public static void runAStarSearch(Node start, Node goal, int[][] grid) {

        boolean keepSearching = true;

        ArrayList<Node> openList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Stack<Node> path = new Stack<Node>();

        // has to do with binary heap, has to put value in starting position 0,
        // then add
        openList.add(start);
        openList.add(start);
        System.out.println("Adding Node: " + start.toString());

        while (keepSearching) {

            // pops node n from openList
            Node n = removeFromHeap(openList);
            System.out.println("Popping " + n.toString());

            // checks for goal state
            if (n.equals(goal)) {
                System.out.println("\tPath:");
                keepSearching = false;
                while (!n.equals(start)) {
                    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // printing path backwards, want to print the correct way!
                    while (n.getParent() != null) {
                        System.out.println(" -> " + n.getParent().toString());

                        n = n.getParent();
                    } // ends while loop

                    if (!n.equals(start) && n.getParent() == null) {
                        System.out.println("No path found!");
                    }// ends if
                }// ends while loop
            } else {

                // find all possible neighbors
                int r = n.getRow();
                int c = n.getCol();

                for (int i = r - 1; i <= r + 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = c - 1; j <= c + 1; j++) {

                        if (i >= 0 && i < 15 && j >= 0 && j < 15
                                && (i != r || j != c) && grid[i][j] != 1) {
                            Node m = new Node(i, j, 0);
                            System.out.println("Generating neighbor: "
                                    + m.toString());
                            m.setParent(n);
                            int newG = 10;
                            if (Math.abs(i - r) + Math.abs(j - c) == 2) {
                                newG = 14;
                            }
                            m.setG(n.getG() + newG);
                            m.setH(getH(m, goal));
                            m.setF();

                            if (containedInList(m, closedList) == null) {
                                Node q = containedInList(m, openList);
                                if (q == null) {
                                    addToHeap(openList, m);
                                    System.out.println("Adding Node: "
                                            + m.toString());
                                } else {
                                    if (m.getG() < q.getG()) {
                                        q.setG(m.getG());
                                        q.setParent(n);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedList.add(n);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Node removeFromHeap(ArrayList<Node> openList) {
        // pop node at root to return at the end
        Node n = openList.get(0);

        // get index of node at the end of the heap
        int childIndex = openList.size() - 1;

        // put that node at the root of the tree
        openList.set(1, openList.get(childIndex));

        // get rid of the last node
        openList.remove(childIndex);

        // get location of node to swap down (starting at root)
        int index = 1;

        // loop while there is a left child
        while (index * 2 < openList.size()) {

            int lIndex = index * 2;
            int lValue = openList.get(lIndex).getF();

            // get index of right child
            int rIndex = index * 2 + 1;
            int rValue = lValue + 1;

            // check to see if right child exists
            if (rIndex < openList.size()) {
                rValue = openList.get(rIndex).getF();
            }

            // check for swap
            if (openList.get(index).getF() > Math.min(lValue, rValue)) {
                // swap with left
                if (lValue < rValue) {
                    openList.set(0, openList.get(lIndex));
                    openList.set(lIndex, openList.get(index));
                    openList.set(index, openList.get(0));
                    index = lIndex;
                } else { // swap with right
                    openList.set(0, openList.get(rIndex));
                    openList.set(rIndex, openList.get(index));
                    openList.set(index, openList.get(0));
                    index = rIndex;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static void addToHeap(ArrayList<Node> openList, Node m) {
        // add to next position in the heap
        openList.add(m);

        // get index of node just added
        int childIndex = openList.size() - 1;

        while (childIndex > 1) {

            // get parent node's value
            int parentIndex = childIndex / 2;

            // check for swap
            if (openList.get(childIndex).getF() < openList.get(parentIndex)
                    .getF()) {

                openList.set(0, openList.get(parentIndex));
                openList.set(parentIndex, openList.get(childIndex));
                openList.set(childIndex, openList.get(0));

                childIndex = parentIndex;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getH(Node s, Node g) {
        int rowDif = Math.abs(s.getRow() - g.getRow() * 10);
        int colDif = Math.abs(s.getCol() - g.getCol() * 10);

        return (rowDif + colDif);
    }

    public static Node containedInList(Node n, ArrayList<Node> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(n)) {
                return list.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void generatePath(Node n) {
        // n is our goal node
        // n.parent is the node right before goal node
        // n.parent.parent
        while (n != null) {
            int row = n.getRow();
            int col = n.getCol();
            grid[row][col] = 2;
            n = n.getParent();
        }
    }
}
```

Node Class:

```
public class Node {

    private int row, col, f, g, h, type;
    private Node parent;


    public Node(int r, int c, int t){
        row = r;
        col = c;
        type = t;
        parent = null;
        //type 0 is traverseable, 1 is not
    }

    //mutator methods to set values
    public void setF(){
        f = g + h;
    }
    public void setG(int value){
        g = value;
    }
    public void setH(int value){
        h = value;
    }
    public void setParent(Node n){
        parent = n;
    }

    //accessor methods to get values
    public int getF(){
        return f;
    }
    public int getG(){
        return g;
    }
    public int getH(){
        return h;
    }

    public Node getParent(){
        return parent;
    }
    public int getRow(){
        return row;
    }
    public int getCol(){
        return col;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object in){
        //typecast to Node
        Node n = (Node) in;

        return row == n.getRow() && col == n.getCol();
    }


    public String toString(){       
        return ("Node: " + "(" + row + "," + col + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never inserting nodes into `closedList`

Comment: isnt it inserted into the closed list after all the curly braces? it says {closedList.add(n);

Comment: @ChristieBayne Where's your `Node` class? Nearly 300 lines of code and it's not executable..

Comment: I will edit and attach my Node class

Comment: @ChristieBayne first run with (0, 0) to (14, 14) gave an infinite loop, second run with the same points gave an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at this line `openList.set(1, openList.get(childIndex));` inside `removeFromHeap`..

Comment: @ChristieBayne How does your `removeFromHeap` function deal with an openList of size 0 and size 1? It doesn't seem to be working too well..

Comment: It sets 0 as a placeholder and starts at 1, position 0 is a temp placeholder to save memory

Comment: but that is exactly my problem, sometimes it loops infinitely, and sometimes I get the results, I have it printing out now in the proper order, but how do I get it to print the last node of goal? it only prints from start to the one just before goal.

Comment: It looks like I will have to do further research on the binary heap thing, this was a suggestion from a fellow classmate

Comment: @ChristieBayne Check your prompting for the 'endRow' and 'endCol', for a blocked tile. You are saving the values in 'startRow' and 'startCol'.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Gosu! That is fixed. I made a change in removeHeap which seems to have fixed the inconsistency problem I think! One more thing guys....How do I get my final path to print out the goal node?

Comment: For path printing, I would go with a little recursive function that you give a stringbuilder and a node to as parameters. return if null; else call on parent; then add that node to stringbuilder in appropriately formatted way. This way you start processing at the goal node and print out in the correct direction. (Do note that this uses one stack frame for each node, for long paths consider building your own stack - with a library implementation - rather than using the call stack)